# How I can write something similar to Linq .Any() when writing sql server queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have the following linq query inside my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
Public IQuerable<Technologies> Search (int? isManaged , bool PrimaryCustomerOnly, int?customerID  )
{

var technology2 = ITSys.Technologies

.Where(a => (

( !isManaged.HasValue||a.IsManaged == isManaged)

&& 
(!PrimaryCustomerOnly && a.ITSysFirewall.FirewallCustomers.Any(a2 => customerID.HasValue && a2.CustomerName.ToLower() == stringcustomerid && relatedresourcesID2.Contains(a.IT360ID.Value)))

));
//code goes here.
}
```

Currently I want to execute the same query , inside an sql server 2008 stored procedure . but I am unable to write something similar to .Any (). So can anyone advice how I can write an sql equivalent to the .Any()?
Thanks

Comment: An EXISTS clause would probably be the closest thing you could fine. Even if they're also often other ways to do this (join / left join clauses for example)

Comment: By the way, it's rather hard to rewrite this query, without knowing 1. your table structure 2. What's in `relatedresourcesID2` (and other variables) for example.

Comment: relatedresourcesID2 is an array of IDS , while the stringcustomerid is a string representation of the customerid

Comment: other doubt : in `relatedresourcesID2.Contains(a.IT360ID.Value)` are your sure that you have a.IT360ID, not a2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

many guessings there (keys for relationship, which table has really IT360ID field, but I would imagine something like that.

```
select t.*
from Technologies t
where IsManaged = @IsManaged 
and @PrimaryCustomerOnly = 0 
and t.IT360ID in (<some elements corresponding to relatedresourcesID2>)-- like ('1', '2', 'adsb')
and exists (select null
        from FirewallCustomers fc
        where t.Id = fc.PrimaryCustomerOnly_Id 
        and fc.customerId is not null 
        and lower(fc.CustomerName) = @stringcustomerid)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) would be the closest that you can get to `.Any()`

Example

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE]
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [TABLE] WHERE NAME IS NOT NULL)
```

would be equivalent to

```
db.Table.Any(o => o.Name != null);
```

This specific query would start like this, and I am not sure how to finish it but it should give you indication in what direction you should go.

```
SELECT * FROM Technologies 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Technologies WHERE (isManaged IS NOT NULL AND isManaged = @MANAGED) AND (PrimaryCustomerOnly == FALSE AND 
// DO THE JOINS a.ITSysFirewall.FirewallCustomers.Any(a2 => customerID.HasValue && a2.CustomerName.ToLower() == stringcustomerid && relatedresourcesID2.Contains(a.IT360ID.Value)))
)
```

Comment: but when i try to write something such as inside my stored procedure "where t.Tag = Tag and r.RESOURCENAME = Name and EXISTS....", the sql server management studio raise an error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition ....", so not sure how to write the EXSTST beside the other conditions ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus That is ironic to say the least :) Thanks.